# span class based on database data PHP and mysql

Tags: php, html

My goal is to give certain words from a table in the database a specific   tag derive from another table in the database using simple PHP, MySQL, and CSS (I use old MySQL and PHP code). Consider these sentences from the database

```
I love fruit like banana
I like that tomorrow will be rain, my brother hates it
I hate strawberry yogurt, however, I like yogurt
```

and these is the words that I want to tag

```
words, type
like, good 
hate, bad
love, good
dislike, bad
```

I create the style so the good word will be tag with green color and bad word will be tag with red color.
Here is my current code

```
 <style >
      .positive{

        background: green;
        background-color:green ;

      }
      .negative{
        background: red;
        background-color:red ;
      }
    </style>
<?php 
                  mysqli_query()....
                  $data=array();
                  //$data[1]=$row['sentences'];
                  $data=[$row['sentences']];
                  echo "$data";

                  $good = array("love", "like");
                  $bad=array("hate","dislike");  
                  for ($j=1;$j<=count($data);$j++)
                  {
                     $data[] 
                    if (in_array("$data[$j]", $good)) {
                        echo "<span class='positive'>$data[$j]</span>";
                    }
                    if (in_array("$data[$j]", $bad)) {
                        echo "<span class='negative'>$data[$j]</span>";
                    }
                  }
?>
```

As you can see I tried to put the sentences from the database in the array, and loop it with comparison from another array. If the word is found in an array, I give the tag with span class.
Desired output

```
I <span class='positive'>love</span> fruit <span class='positive'>like</span> banana
I <span class='positive'>like</span> that tomorrow will be rain, my brother <span class='negative'>hate</span> it
I <span class='negative'>hate</span> strawberry yogurt, however I <span class='positive'>like</span> yogurt
```

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.0+.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: I use mysqli_ , it was a typo in the first draft

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: You are just told us the expected output. You did not talk about what you did. What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: I did the php code, extracting the data from database, put it in array $data=$row['sentences']. I try to loop the words one by one and compared it with good and bad words array, if the words is found I give the tag. Currently, the result only show the sentences from the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you can tackle this problem by converting your string into an array using exclude(" ", $string)

comparing each index the values you have in your array and if the array index matches one of your words. You can easily replace that word with the  and your desired class.

In the end, implode that array and echo the array.

```
<?php

$string = 'this is the string you get from server';
$banWords = ['first','second'];
$string = exclude(' ', $string);

for($i = 0; $i <= count($string); $i++){
    foreach($banWords as $key => $ban){
       if($ban == $string[$i]){
           $string[$i] = "<span class='positive'>".$string[$i]."</span>";
       }
    }
}

$string = implode(' ', $string);

?>
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, could you please give detail like the coding

Comment: Thanks!, my problem was, I did not know exclude and implode function before. Thanks again!